# What is gcc option to ignore unused condition

Tags: gcc, mingw32

```
 #if !__STDC__ && (_MSC_VER <= 1000) && !defined(__BORLANDC__)
 /* For backward compatibility */
 typedef VARIANT_BOOL _VARIANT_BOOL;
 #else
 /* ANSI C/C++ reserve bool as keyword */
 #define _VARIANT_BOOL    /##/
 #endif
```

This code is copied from a header file and #if block is active and #else block is disabled but gcc doesn't ignore inactive block.

....\wtypes.h|1071|error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token

I know what gcc is saying but I don't want to modify the code for different compilers. The code MUST REMAIN UNTOUCHED. 
     How can I tell gcc to ignore unused code?

Comment: "*and #if block is active and #else block is disabled*" - what does this mean? Where is it active / disabled? For me the above code works (on *VStudio*, *Ubtu* and *mingw*).

Comment: It means the first condition is true and else block should be ignored. On editor else block is inactive (inaccessible) but compiler gives error. I came back  here for the same problem  in some other files. GCC starts compiling and by-passes it at first step. Later, when it finds a reference to the bypassed section I expect it to give "undefined symbol ...", but GCC includes bypassed section incorrectly.

Comment: That's because the editor intellisense behaved differently than the compiler. What's the editor you use anyway What *gcc* version? I assume it's on *Win*.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks (17.12) default editor for Mingw32 with gcc 4.92. Editor and compiler goes well together. Editor-compiler mismatching occurs with Visual C++ compiler and Borland compiler, so I cant use  them with Code::Blocks. Borland C++ and Visual C++ compiles that part correctly but I want to migrate  everything into gcc as it seems more convenient for cross-compiling. Currently, I am trying to migrate an old MFC/ATL application. Another problem I found with GCC is that address of opearator (&) is not recognized by GCC. eg: "#define REFCLSID const CLSID &" is an error for GCC.

Comment: OK, that piece of code is really old. Why it shouldn't be modified? Simply remove the ifdefs and only leave the part that you care about (although when I did so `_VARIANT_BOOL` was not defined). so you should stick with the regular process. the `CLSID` stuff is *Win* specific, so you won't have it in *gcc*. You'll have to manually port it yourself. But I think you have very little chances of success at your task. Why do you want to port it under *gcc*? Try with a newer *VStudio* version instead.